# Get phone calling country_code from locale

Tags: java, locale, faker

I'm using java-faker library to generate phone number based on LOCALE.
Number is generated without country code like +1, +44 etc

Is any possibility to get county code from java based on LOCALE?

Can't find any country_code selection in java-faker library, also in LOCALE I don't see that option, but maybe I'm missing something

```
 public static String getPhoneNumber() {
        return getFaker().phoneNumber().cellPhone();
    }

  static Faker getFaker() {
        return new Faker(new Locale(LANGUAGE));
    }
```

Comment: Share your code with us. Although `java-faker` no longer maintained, You should use another lib.

Comment: Which lib is worth to check in your opinion? I have to generate phoneNo, first name, last name and email

Comment: You mean *international calling codes*.

Comment: right, calling codes

Comment: Can you see your locale in supported locales https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker#supported-locales?

Comment: Yes I see, but I don't see a method to get calling code

Comment: So, the project does not support country_code of your locale.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a library level issue, I checked with `locale=de` is able to generate something like `+49-174-4012298` which contained the country code (+49), and you can find more information on the library repo with the config of the code, [[de.yml](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/blob/a8b8ff0acc6fcc629d08a3a9952f83be56a9a3c3/src/main/resources/de.yml) [en-GB.yml](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/blob/a8b8ff0acc6fcc629d08a3a9952f83be56a9a3c3/src/main/resources/en-GB.yml)] perhaps you might want to switch to another data mocking library, code example below.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Faker f = new Faker(new Locale("de"));
        System.out.println(f.phoneNumber().cellPhone());
    }
}
```

[image: Output from my side with locale=de]

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Faker f = new Faker(new Locale("en-GB"));
        System.out.println(f.phoneNumber().cellPhone());
    }
}
```

[image: Output from my side with locale=en-GB]